# Won't followed by noun

Tags: pronouns, word-order, future

I try to understand the song 'Sober' by band Tool. And there are couple of sentence with won't followed by pronoun or noun and without verb. For example:

```
'Jesus, won't you f*cking whistle nothing 
 But the past and done.'

'Mother Mary won't you whisper nothing
but the past and done.'
```

Also, I've seen same sentence in the 'Passeneger' by Deftones:

```
Chrome buttons, buckles and leather surfaces
These and other lucky witnesses
Now to calm me
**This time won't you please**
Drive faster
Roll the windows down
```

Maybe in Tool's lyrics it is interrogative with dot instead of question mark, but sentence by Deftones I can't understand at all. How should I interpret this?

Comment: What do you mean, "without verb"? "Won't you whistle", "won't you whisper", "won't you please drive faster". These are all verbs. Also, in its current form, the question is a better fit for our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2), as this construction is rather common, and no native speaker will have trouble interpreting it.

Comment: Here, *whisper* is a verb. And *"Won't you please drive faster?"* is one sentence.

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the site, I thought this site for learners:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Won't you please drive faster" is a slightly more insistent variant of "Please drive faster".